# Table 'X' has no column named 'Y' en SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación para el trabajo en mi universidad. Es una aplicación en la que tengo que registrar los usuarios mediante un formulario en el que se van a meter varios Datos.
He hecho un código creando una base de datos con SQLite pero al terminarla he introducir unos datos de prueba y me ha salido un error diciendo que no se pueden insertar los datos.

Esta es la clase donde tengo las constantes y la sentencia SQL.

```
    public static final String TABLA_USUARIO = "usuario";
    public static final String NOMBRE = "nombre";
    public static final String EDAD = "edad";
    public static final String CIUDAD = "ciudad";
    public static final String CODIGOPOSTAL = "codigoPostal";
    public static final String SEXO = "sexo";
    public static final String PAIS = "pais";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO = "CREATE TABLE" +TABLA_USUARIO+ "("+NOMBRE+ " TEXT, "+EDAD+" INTEGER, "+CIUDAD+" TEXT, "+CODIGOPOSTAL+" INTEGER, "+SEXO+" TEXT, "+PAIS+" TEXT)";
```

Esta es la función guarda los datos en la BD

```
private void registrarUsuario() {
    UsuariosDbHelper conn = new UsuariosDbHelper(this, "bd_usuario", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Utilidades.NOMBRE, campoNombre.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.EDAD, campoEdad.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CIUDAD, campoCiudad.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CODIGOPOSTAL, campoCodPostal.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.SEXO, campoSexo.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.PAIS, campoPais.getText().toString());

   long resultado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, Utilidades.NOMBRE, values);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resultado: " + resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}
```

Al lanzar la aplicación y meter unos datos de prueba me aparece este error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table usuario has no column named codigoPostal (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO usuario(sexo,pais,nombre,codigoPostal,edad,ciudad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

He hecho muchas pruebas así que puede ser que la primera vez se me creara la BD mal. Quería saber como arreglarlo o como poder borrar la tabla y volverla a crear para que funcione.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como arreglar que cosa? o creas la tabla de vuelta, o vas a tener que hacer un alter. Entiendo tu problema, mas no como llegaste a el...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error indica que al realizar la consulta no existe el campo `codigoPostal` en tu tabla `usuario`

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table usuario has no column
>   named codigoPostal (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   usuario(sexo,pais,nombre,codigoPostal,edad,ciudad) VALUES
>   (?,?,?,?,?,?)

en este caso veo un error primeramente en tu Query, debes agregar espacios para que tu query que se usa para crear la tabla no sea incorrecto:

```
// public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO = "CREATE TABLE" +TABLA_USUARIO+ "("+NOMBRE+ " TEXT, "+EDAD+" INTEGER, "+CIUDAD+" TEXT, "+CODIGOPOSTAL+" INTEGER, "+SEXO+" TEXT, "+PAIS+" TEXT)";
public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLA_USUARIO+ " ("+NOMBRE+ " TEXT, "+EDAD+" INTEGER, "+CIUDAD+" TEXT, "+CODIGOPOSTAL+" INTEGER, "+SEXO+" TEXT, "+PAIS+" TEXT)";
```

Después de realizar esto, elimina el caché de tu aplicación y vuelve a subirla, probablemente tienes una versión incorrecta de la tabla que se creo sin ese campo.

Answer (score 0):

estás olvidando poner la llave primaria. Crea otra columna con un Id que sea la llave primaria

```
"CREATE TABLE " +
                    nombreTabla +
                    " (" + idTabla +
                    " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +...
```